# Largest Single Movement in Array

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, java-8

The poles that hold our devices can sway a bit in the wind. Suppose we track the amount a pole has swayed over time as a sequence of values, where each value corresponds to degrees of tilt in one dimension taken at uniform time intervals. For example, [-1, 0, 1] would indicate 1 degree of tilt to the left at t=0 0 degrees of tilt (vertical) at t=1 1 degree of tilt to the right at t=2.

Now write a function that will determine the largest single movement in degrees the device made from one direction to another given a sequence of tilt values.

> For example, given the input: [1, 0, -1, 2, 3, 1]
> The function should output:
> {“t2”: "-1," “t4”: 3}

Explanation: The device swayed right to left 2 degrees from t0 to t2, left to right 4 degrees from t2 to t4, and right to left 2 degrees from t4 to t5. The largest single movement was left to right 4 degrees from t=2 to t=4. Explain the time and space complexity of your function.

Was not able to code it, not sure, what approach is best suited for this sort of question.Can you please help.

```
static int[] largestSingleMovement(int arr[]){
int x = arr.length;




}
```

Comment: This type of problems are purposed to enhance your own programming skills. What's the point if you are asking for complete solution without trying it yourself? If it's your homework then StackOverflow is a wrong choice to ask at.

Comment: not homework, but a competitive coding interview question. I could not do it, so thought to ask how one should approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, here's what you can think of doing:

1. Create an array "`signums`" of length `arr.length - 1` which holds the [signum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) of the differences between consecutive values in `arr`.
2. Loop over `signums`, and any time the last non-zero signum value is not the same as the current non-zero signum value, take note of the absolute value of the difference between the corresponding original inputs in `arr`. Keep track of the largest absolute difference.
3. Return the largest absolute difference.

But you can factor out the intermediate step of creating the signum array. Try to think of how.